# Control the flow of ViewEngines

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

Having a custom view engine installed on my web app:

ViewEngines.Engines.Insert(0, new CustomViewEngine1());
...and the second is the default MVC View Engine for Razor

And having the definition of my first view engine:

```
public class CustomViewEngine1: RazorViewEngine
    {
        public CustomViewEngine1(): this(null)
        { }
        public CustomViewEngine1(IViewPageActivator viewPageActivator)
        {
            ViewLocationFormats = new string[] { "~/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml", "~/../Framework.Web/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml", "~/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml", "~/../Framework.Web/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml"  };
            MasterLocationFormats = new string[] { "~/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml", "~/../Framework.Web/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml", "~/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml", "~/../Framework.Web/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml"  };
            PartialViewLocationFormats = new string[] { "~/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml", "~/../Framework.Web/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml", "~/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml", "~/../Framework.Web/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml" };
            FileExtensions = new string[] { "cshtml" };
        }
        protected override IView CreatePartialView (ControllerContext controllerContext, string partialPath)
        {
           if (controllerContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice)
           {
              return base.CreatePartialView(controllerContext, partialPath);
           }
           else
           {
              //...What i have to put here in order to let the control to the next route engine in the collection ViewEngines.Engines
           }           
        }
        protected override IView CreateView (ControllerContext controllerContext, string viewPath, string masterPath)
        {
           if (controllerContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice)
           {
            return base.CreateView(controllerContext, viewPath, masterPath);
           }
           else
           {
              //...What i have to put here in order to let the control to the next route engine in the collection ViewEngines.Engines
           }
        }
    }
```

How could i complete the code (where i have the comments ) in order that if the request has been not made by a mobile device, uses the view engine that comes next in ViewEngines collection? (which is the default MVC Razor View engine).

Thanks in advance.

Regards.

Jose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this blog post is a good starting point for you: [A Better ASP.NET MVC Mobile Device Capabilities ViewEngine](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ABetterASPNETMVCMobileDeviceCapabilitiesViewEngine.aspx)